# Finding an entire function such that $|f(z)| \leq |\exp(z)|$ and $f(\pi i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I have just been introduced to (generalised) Liouville's theorem which tell us that if an entire function is bounded by some monomial $m |z|^n$, then we know that the function is in fact a polynomial of  at most degree $n$. Now when I got to the exercises, this was the first exercise:

> Find an entire function such that  $\forall z \in \mathbb C$, we have that $|f(z)| \leq |\exp(z)|$ and $f(\pi i)=i$.

Of course, we can express the exponential as a power series, as how it is often originally defined, but this is not a polynomial. My assumption would be that in fact $f(z)= \exp(z/2)$, this would satisfy the second property. I do however run into trouble because take for instance $\exp(-5) < \exp(-5/2)$, this does not satisfy the first property. I am still struggling with seeing a good approach how one goes about and finds these entire functions satisfying such properties. Does anyone have any good pointers as to a general approach I could try?

Comment: Correction: it's a polynomial of degree ***at most*** $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply take $f(z)=-ie^z$. That will work.

Comment: Oh, yes indeed, nice tweak.

Comment: Here we abuse that fact that we can have equality a bit, I like it, thank you José.

Comment: @WesleyStrik Actually $f(z)/ e^{z}$ is a bounded entire function, hence a constant. So the only candidates for $f$ are those of the type $ce^{z}$ and the solution did not come out of a hat!.

Comment: Thanks, this also made me justify why my gut feeling was correct, it is always a good approach to divide out by the function, apply the property of norms and check i this indeed still is an entire function, which this is, and then apply Liouville to it. That is, what you are saying is: $$ |f(z)| \leq |\exp(z)| \implies |f(z) / \exp(z)| \leq 1$$ now we apply Liouville and get that $f(z)/\exp(z)$ is constant, so $f(z) = c \exp(z)$, we fill in the condition $f(\pi i)=i$ and we get that $c=-i$